# Send user's geolocation to server every minute

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, geolocation

I'm trying to write a application that sends user's geolocation to MYSQL database every minute or so. This is the code I have right now, but it's not working. How do i need to change this to make it work?

JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
setInterval ( "onPositionUpdate()", 10000 );
function onPositionUpdate(position)
            {
                var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                var lng = position.coords.longitude;
                jQuery.ajax({ type: "POST", 
                    url:  "myURL/location.php", 
                    data: 'x='+lat+ '&y='+lng , 
                    cache: false, 
                        });
                        }

            if(navigator.geolocation)
               navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onPositionUpdate);
            else
                alert("navigator.geolocation is not available");



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and PHP:

```
<?php
  include 'config.php';

  // database connection
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

  // new data

  $x = @$_POST['x'];
  $y = @$_POST['y'];
  // query
  $sql = "update locations set x=?, y=? where username = asd";
  $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $q->execute(array($x), ($y));
?>
```

And I suppose this is not the right way to send multiple variables, is it?. Firebug's console shows me

```
 missing } after property list
[Break On This Error]   

data: 'x='+lon+'&y='+lat;
```

When I use only one value, it POSTs that variable to server only once and after that console gives:

```
position is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

var lat = position.coords.latitude;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do something like:

```
var currPosition;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    updatePosition(position);
    setInterval(function(){
        var lat = currPosition.coords.latitude;
        var lng = currPosition.coords.longitude;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url:  "myURL/location.php", 
            data: 'x='+lat+'&y='+lng, 
            cache: false
        });
    }, 1000);
}, errorCallback); 

var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
    updatePosition(position);
});

function updatePosition( position ){
    currPosition = position;
}

function errorCallback(error) {
    var msg = "Can't get your location. Error = ";
    if (error.code == 1)
        msg += "PERMISSION_DENIED";
    else if (error.code == 2)
        msg += "POSITION_UNAVAILABLE";
    else if (error.code == 3)
        msg += "TIMEOUT";
    msg += ", msg = "+error.message;

    alert(msg);
}
```

Comment: how can i send the position every minute? 

setInterval ( "updatePosition()", 60000 );?

Comment: why do you need to send the position every minute? it's sent automatically it it changes

Comment: oh, ok. Console showed it posting only once so I thought that it would send location only once. But thanks, this will work

Comment: Im sorry but I think I can't accept this answer. Because if the values are sent to server everytime position changes, it will be very hard for the servers if there is many devices sending the values at the same time. So I think I need to watchPosition, but send the values only every minute. Could you provide me a sample code on how to do this?

Comment: sending position every minute will be worst then sending position only if it changes for the server, you can just store a `session` for current location in your `PHP` script instead of sending an `AJAX` request every minute :/

Comment: why will it be worse for server to send position every minute than send position 30 times in a minute? If I have like 50 users sending data at the same time wont it use a lot of servers potential compared to sending it only once in a minute?

Comment: @sal this doesnt make sense as there is no insert statement anywhere and you cant do a Update and SET first???